# MYSQL update query returns zero line while same select query provides result (search field IS NULL)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, null, sql-update

I want to update lines with testing 2 fields.
When I proceed a select query, I can see the concerned records:

```
SELECT * FROM `t_journal` WHERE Type IS NULL and Mouvement < 0
```

But when I use the same filter on an UPDATE query, MYSQL return zero line :

```
UPDATE t_journal SET Type = "Entree" WHERE Type IS NULL AND Mouvement < 0
```

I tried on a local copy of my table in MAMP with Mysql 5.7.32 (PHPMyAdmin) and also live on Ubuntu server with MYSQL 5.5.62 ... same result.

**EDIT**
When I simulate the query this shows this result

```
SQL query:
UPDATE t_journal SET Type = "Entree" WHERE Type is null AND Mouvement < 0
Matched rows: 0
```

What am I doing a wrong ?

**EDIT 2:**

[image: Select SQL query with NULL condition]

Comment: *But when I use the same filter on an UPDATE query, MYSQL return zero line* MySQL must return `Matched: X, affected: Y, warnings: Z`. What of 3 values are zeros? Does `X` is zero?

Comment: please see Question Edit for the MYSQL response when I simulate the query

Comment: Post some results from `SELECT * FROM t_journal WHERE Type IS NULL and Mouvement < 0` query

Comment: please see Question Edit 2 for IMG of SELECT results